# jPlayer mobile http request (not working)

Tags: jquery, audio, mobile, mp3, jplayer

I'm using jPlayer for a site and everything's working fine, however on mobile devices I can't seem to get any audio - all mp3 http requests are being canceled with no preview or response. I am able to play the mp3 on mobile (tested on android) with the direct link.

https://www.lisssten.com/

Here's the function that plays the mp3's. I've tried different audio files, using flash etc but nothing seems to work, so I can only assume it's a request issue:

```
$('.jp-jplayer').each(function(index, val){

  $(this).jPlayer({

    ready: function() {

      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: 'audio/file'+ (index + 1) +'.mp3',
      })
      .bind($.jPlayer.event.volumechange, volumeCallback);

    },    
    solution: "html, flash",
    supplied: "mp3",
    preload: "auto",
    swfPath: 'js',
    loop: true,
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to specify that you supply an m4a instead of a mp3, but still keep the link to the mp3, like this:

```
$('.jp-jplayer').each(function(index, val){

  $(this).jPlayer({

    ready: function() {

      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        m4a: 'audio/file'+ (index + 1) +'.mp3',
      })
      .bind($.jPlayer.event.volumechange, volumeCallback);

    },    
    solution: "html, flash",
    supplied: "m4a",
    preload: "auto",
    swfPath: 'js',
    loop: true,
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm afraid that didn't work, it stopped the file playing even in chrome